# grails how to configure log4j to log to tomcat logs

Tags: grails, log4j, tomcat6

Every time that I start up my grails application, using the production environment on my tomcat6 server I see the following error in /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: stacktrace.log (Permission denied)
...
...
```

I gather that this is becaues log4j is attempting to create a log file and doesn't have the required permissions.

Ideally I would like the log files for my application to go to either the existing tomcat log (/var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out) or to go to a separate file in the /var/log/tomcat6 directory.

How can I change the location of the log4j logs with the minimal amount of configuration possible? i.e. I don't want to define a complete appender with it's own output pattern, I just want to change the location of the log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup logging to use file by configuring it in `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        file name:'file', file: '/var/log/tomcat6/mylog.log'
    }
    root {
        info 'stdout', 'file'
    }
}
```

at this case all log event with level `info` and above will be pushed into both file `/var/log/tomcat6/mylog.log` and stdout (that tomcat will add to `catalina.out` by himself)

See: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.2%20Logging

Comment: You can avoid hard-coding the path to Tomcat's logs dir like this: `file name: 'file',  file: (System.getProperty('catalina.base') ?: 'target') + '/logs/mylog.log'` - this works in run-app or in Tomcat since if the `catalina.base` property isn't set it writes logs to target/logs

Comment: Also doesn't the logging in Tomcat redirect the console logger into catalina.out?

Comment: I've set the appender file attribute to '/var/log/tomcat6/mylog.log' and this created the log file and is logging to it. However I'm still seeing the above error in the 'catalina.out' log. Does anyone know a quick way I can tell which file log4j is trying to access when it throws this error?